# SortedArrayUsingComparator not working accurately

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsnumber

I am trying to sort my array, but it seems to not work reliably.

Here is the code for sorting. Basically the Request priorityID has values from 1-5
For example:
[image]

```
 sortedArray = [self.selectedReqArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
            NSLog(@"Value A: %@", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[(Request*)a priorityID]]);
            NSLog(@"Value B %@", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[(Request*)b priorityID]]);
            NSNumber *first = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[(Request*)a priorityID]];
            NSNumber *second = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[(Request*)b priorityID]];
            return [first compare:second];
        }];

        self.sortedReqArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];
```

Sometimes it's sorting correctly 1-5, but sometimes it sorts 1 2 4 5 3...

Then when I go to take a look at the NSLog it's spitting out really big values when they should just be 1-5.

Here is sample output

`Value B 168492640
Value A: 168492640
Value B 168492640
Value A: 174580912
Value B 168492640
Value A: 174580912
Value B 168492640
Value A: 174580912
Value B 168492640
Value A: 174580912
Value B 168492640
Value A: 174580912`

What is happening? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the debugger display `[(Request*)a priorityID]` seems to be a `NSNumber`, but 
you are treating it as *integer* (so you are actually comparing the *addresses* of the objects).

This following should work:

```
sortedArray = [self.selectedReqArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
            NSNumber *first = [(Request*)a priorityID];
            NSNumber *second = [(Request*)b priorityID];
            return [first compare:second];
        }];
```

A perhaps slightly more elegant way to write this is

```
sortedArray = [self.selectedReqArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Request* a, Request* b) {
            NSNumber *first = [a priorityID];
            NSNumber *second = [b priorityID];
            return [first compare:second];
        }];
```

If the `Request` class is Key-Value Coding compliant for the key `priorityID`, the
following should also work:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"priorityID" ascending:YES];
sortedArray = [self.selectedReqArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

Comment: you are the bomb! yea that solved the problem and I modified it to the elegant version. Thanks a lot!